# How to convert submitted form array to this array on php?

Tags: php, arrays, forms

Lets suppose i have the following array submitted by a html form:

```
array(
    'firstname' => array('Sara','Jim'),
    'lastname'  => array('Gibson','Jobs')
);
```

What i wanna achieve is the following array:

```
array(
    array(
        'firstname' => 'sara',
        'lastname'  => 'Gibson'
    ),
    array(
        'firstname' => 'Jim',
        'lastname'  => 'Jim'
    )
);
```

I need a function to automatically sort the array not manually by entering data but automatically processing array data.

Comment: It looks to me as if your form needs re-factoring to return the array you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anything wrong with @Tim Cooper's solution, but if you don't want to mention the keys manually, you can also use:

```
$new_arr = array();
foreach ($arr as $key => $value)
{
  foreach ($value as $numkey => $value2)
  {
    $new_arr[$numkey][$key] = $value2;
  }
}
```

Comment: @Jared Farrish Wow, that was fast!

Comment: Seeing @drfanai's comment in the other answer, I figured this was what they were after. It was accepted briefly...

Comment: @Jared Farrish Yes, I noticed that too after I submitted, but I actually meant you converting it to a working demo. Need to remember that page...

Answer (score 2):

```
$new_arr = array();
$length = count($arr['firstname']);
for($i = 0; $i < $length; $i++)
{
   $new_arr[] = array('firstname' => $arr['firstname'][$i], 'lastname' => $arr['lastname'][$i]);
}
```

Comment: I want a function to automatically sort the array not manually by entering data.

Comment: @drfanai:  I'm not sure I understand what you mean.  There was nothing related to sorting in the question.

Comment: @Tim Cooper what i mean about sorting was converting the first array to the second array.something like `function arrayConverter($myfirstarray){return $secondarray;}`

Comment: @Tim Cooper your function is dependent on explicitly entering 'firstname','lastname',etc.